# How to keep Visual Studio from treating files as components or forms

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Today I noticed that Visual Studio 2008 always treats a file as if it was a component or a form if this file contains a definition of one.

This means that it always opens the designer by default. I think this behavior is very annoying, because a file containing a class that derives from form or control does not have to be an actual form or control and I want to edit the source by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just repeat the solution I found at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da/winformsdesigner/thread/cdfd7e6f-3ffc-4969-9ce1-c1ca0f08ae67

Add the DesignerCategory attribute to your class like this:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]
public class Foo : FormDerivedClass
```

Answer (score 3):

A class that derives from `Form` will always be a `Form`; this is a fundamental concept of object orientation. That said, you can alter the default behavior:

- Right-click the file in question, select *"Open with..."* in the context menu
- In the dialog, select *"Source code (Text) editor..."*
- Click the *"Set as default"* button
- Click OK

Comment: This would open all forms with the editor by default, right?
That wouldn't be the behavior I wanted.

I thought it should be possible with attributes or something.

You are right that a class that derives from form is a form, but the file can contain other classes etc or the form class could be inside another class where treating the file as a form would not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file, Open With, select preferred editor from the list, Set as Default. Although this works for all files of that type, not for a single file.